# TeX yells at me that the `xxivtime` option in `datetime` can't be found, but it's there

Tags: datetime

I've been using `\usepackage[ddmmyyyy,xxivtime]{datetime}` to timestamp compilations of a document somewhat longer than this one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy,xxivtime]{datetime}
\begin{document}
Version of \currenttime, \today.
\end{document}
```

Every time I run my document, LaTeX tells me that the `xxivtime` option can't be found in `datetime.sty`, but if I ignore this warning, it prints times in the proper format anyway.

More explicitly, it gives me this error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datetime/datetime.sty:522: LaTeX Error: Unknown option `xxivtime' for package `datetime'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.522 \if@dt@nodate
```

Yet, when I go to TeX Live Utility and look for the package and search out the `xxivtime` option in `datetime.sty`, it's in there. Why is it angry at me?

Comment: I can see a `24hr` option with the definition `\DeclareOption{24hr}{\settimeformat{xxivtime}}` but no `xxivtime` option.

Comment: That `24hr` option works. I had seen it suggested online that `xxivtime` was the relevant thing, but hadn't realized that it needed to be called with `\settimeformat{xxivtime}`. Thank you for setting me straight.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to convert your comment into a short answer?

Comment: @samcarter done.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! One less in the unanswered list!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see in the code a `24hr` option with the definition

```
\DeclareOption{24hr}{\settimeformat{xxivtime}}
```

but no `xxivtime` option.